# Is QT for Embedded Linux VNC Server internet enabled?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded, vnc, qnetworkrequest

I'm developing an application using QT which uses QNetworkRequest to get response from a HTTP server. I'm wondering if it is possible to test/debug thru the VNC? Is the VNC server connected to internet?

This is a general question so I don't think code is required, I have been googling but couldn't find any clue yet.

Appreciate your help!. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded device is connected to internet, why not?